# Angular UI-slider, update model when user drops mouse key

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Is there anyway to configure angular-ui slider so the model is updated only when user drops mouse key? Instead of changing the value in realtime?

Reason is performance. I make heavy calculations when everytime my moodel changes.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-slider

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *ng-click* or *ng-change*, try **ng-mouseup**. It'll do the trick.

Comment: there is a problem with this approach if user will move knob and drop it having mouse cursor not directly above element with `ng-mouseup`

Answer (score 0):

There's not a way to configure it, however it seems feasible that you could fork this and convert the elm.bind('slide') call to elm.bind('slidestop'), which would only trigger after the user is done sliding the handle.

EDIT: You could also listen for both, and publish an event from the directive via $rootScope.$broadcast when the user stops sliding the handle, and do your calculations when the subscriber receives that event.